# Web Api model validation result in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Having Web Api model like this:

```
 public class Meel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string VaskNr { get; set; }
}
```

And my API controller for Post is

```
  public IHttpActionResult PostMeel(Meel meel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        db.Meels.Add(meel);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = meel.Id }, meel);
    }
```

I call my Web Api from an MVC Client like this:

```
 public ActionResult Create(MeelModel model)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3806/");
        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<MeelModel>("api/meels", model).Result;
        return View(model);
    }
```

My question is how can I return validation result i.e. "VaskNr is required" to my View. My View is generated by MVC template. When using only an MVC application without Web API it is no problem to return the error to the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create a Filter that returns the modelstate as json

Filter:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

Setting filter for all controllers:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelAttribute());

        // ...
    }
}
```

Setting filter for one controller:

```
[ValidateModel]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Product product)
{
    // ...
}
```

see: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: But in my case I have ActionResult in the client application (you have HttpResposeMessage) is there any difference? Suppose the filer is a separate class in web Api application. Am I right?

Comment: This doesn't affect what the client action returns. This should go on your api. Then the response from the api will be json serialised model state, so if the validation fails on the api then the 'response' variable in the client action will be that.